# EJB2 on different JBoss versions

Tags: jboss, ejb

I need to use some EJBs which are deployed on JBoss version 4.x from another EJB deployed on JBoss version 3.2.x. Is this possible?

I ask because I have a third party application which uses some strange bridge's to do that and don't know why (though I haven't try to do this on my own).

Answer (score 4):

This is unfortunately not possible. One of the major drawbacks of remote EJBs is that there is nothing in the specification that guarantees or even suggests any kind of interoperability between different vendors or between different EJB versions from the same vendor.

In practice I found that at least with JBoss AS it never works. Even minor upgrades break binary compatibility completely. There have been some very hacky attempts with special class loaders that are only been given access to the client libs of the target JBoss AS, but this is very tricky to get right.

I guess this "strange bridge" you are talking about is using such a trick. Kudos to whoever build that bridge for getting this to work at all.

See this topic I started on the JBoss community forum for some more details: http://community.jboss.org/message/587180