# What is the point of web services?

Tags: web-services, rest, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

I really don't see the point of making EJB's into web services.  The first thing that comes to mind is security.  How do I keep the entire world from using my business methods?  How would you authenticate a user to use a service.  The second it seems hard to pass objects or if it's even possible to pass lists into a web service.

I can see some justifications such as having services for multiple applications that use the same methods.  But why not just have a library or deploy an ear with all the business methods?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Buy a book or google Introduction to webservices

Comment: A 1 second search turned up this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service - surely you could have invested that much time instead of posting a non-question here? Voting to close.

Comment: I see there are basically 2 parts of your question, one more or less implied.

 - Why use http/text based communication instead of binary?
 - Why use remote communication at all?

Comment: It might seem like a hassle to use http and text based communication. Marshalling objects or collections of objects can indeed be a little troublesome, but the various webservices technologies have large automated this. So yes, it is definitely possible to pass (send/receive) objects into web services.

Comment: Now the implied question seems to be why? Why bother?

There are various answers here. One of them that especially applies to EJB is that binary compatibility can be very bad. See for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100634/ejb2-on-different-jboss-versions. Using webservices even for Java to Java communication has the advantage that it works between different EJB providers or between different versions of EJB providers.

Comment: The second one which has been mentioned above is to interoperate between totally different platforms. EJB communication only works between Java clients (in theory CORBA clients could interoperate as well, but in practice this often fails). *WS (SOAP) communication works between Java and among others ASP.NET. ReST based communication works between Java and basically everything that can fire an HTTP request.

Comment: Then finally there is the sys admin thing. Through the years system administrators have blocked each and every port in corporate firewalls, except for port 80 (HTTP). Many binary protocols (like EJB's IIOP) need elaborate amounts of ports and even callback ports. This works on a LAN, but not beyond that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you like to deploy your Java package to .NET client? Or better how would you like to deploy your Java package to 1.000.000 iPhones?

Web services are here because of interoperability. You will use them to pass data between processes without making the processes dependent on concrete technology. The communication will only be dependent on some interoperable and broadly supported protocols and data structures represented in XML or other interchangable format (like JSON).

If you need some advanced protocols for transaction flow, message level security or reliable messaging you will build SOAP service. If you need lightweight service for broad variety of clients you will build REST service.

Web services have its place and once you will have to build interoperable application or generally logic used by non Java code you will find them useful.